# Running a simple Scala.React expression

Tags: scala, reactive-programming

I am looking into [Scala.React](https://github.com/ingoem/scala-react), and the updated [paper on the issue](https://infoscience.epfl.ch/record/176887), trying to get a simple `Signal` based example to work.

I understand that the `Signal` method in the paper doesn't exist as such, but instead there are `Strict` and `Lazy`. So my naive first attempt:

Setting up the whole thing:

```
object dom extends scala.react.Domain {
  val engine    = new Engine
  val scheduler = new ManualScheduler
}
import dom._
```

Trying out composition:

```
val v1, v2 = Var(0)

val f = Strict { v1() + v2() }
```

The second line crashes with

```
java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: This method must be run on its domain
  scala.react.NilDebug@4eaf6cb1
    at scala.Predef$.assert(Predef.scala:179)
    at scala.react.Debug.assertInTurn(Debug.scala:37)
    at scala.react.EngineModule$Propagator.defer(EngineModule.scala:120)
        ...
```

So I must be doing something wrong. But what?

---

Second attempt:

```
scala> dom.start()

scala> var v1, v2, f = (null: Signal[Int])
v1: dom.Signal[Int] = null
v2: dom.Signal[Int] = null
f: dom.Signal[Int] = null

scala> schedule { v1 = Var(0); v2 = Var(0) }

scala> schedule { f = Strict { v1() + v2() }}

scala> engine.runTurn()

scala> schedule { println(f.now) }

scala> engine.runTurn()
Uncaught exception in turn!
scala.react.EngineModule$LevelMismatch$
```

Comment: I would love to get into reactive programming, but I have the impression that Scala.React is not maintained any more. Therefore, I am very reluctant to use it.

Comment: I have the same problem in getting a simple examle runnning, see [Simple Example for Scala React](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19386516/simple-example-for-scala-react)

Comment: @Madoc Yes, I wouldn't bet on it for production, I was just trying it out. Also the CPS compiler plugin will be abandoned as far as I know. Probably best is to wait for Haller/Miller publishing the source code of [RAY](http://infoscience.epfl.ch/record/188383/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so first of all we should use `Lazy` instead of `Strict` if we want to keep a reference to those signals, because `Strict` requires to be run within a scheduled turn.

The following is my new attempt. Not sure if this is how it's intended, but it works:

```
object Test extends scala.react.Domain with App {
  val engine    = new Engine
  val scheduler = new ManualScheduler

  val v2   = Var(0)
  val v1   = Lazy { v2() + 10 }
  val f    = Lazy { v1() + v2() }

  start()

  schedule {
    new Observing {
      observe(f) { p =>
        println(s"Observed: $p")
      }
    }
    v2() = 5
  }

  runTurn()
}
```